# Print out a csv file in HTML through Python

Tags: python, csv

Basically, the idea is to store comments in a csv file and display them on the same page. The problem is that I want to make the time bold, but I cannot find the location where to do it. I think that the main problem is in HTML file.

```js
from flask import Flask, redirect,render_template,request
import csv
from time import gmtime, strftime

app = Flask(__name__)     

@app.route('/')
def home(): 
    return render_template('home.html')

def readFile(aFile):
#read a file and return a list
    with open(aFile, 'r') as inFile: 
        reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        aList = [row for row in reader] #I think the problem is here
    return aList

def writeFile(aList, aFile):
#write a list to file
    with open(aFile, 'w', newline='') as outFile:
        writer = csv.writer(outFile)
        print(aList)
        writer.writerows(aList)      
    return
    
@app.route('/comments')
def comments():
#read the contacts list from file
    fileName = 'static\\comments.csv'
    commentList = readFile(fileName)
    return render_template('comments.html',commentList=commentList)

@app.route('/addComment', methods = ['POST'])
def addComment():
    #read the contacts list from file
    fileName = 'static\\comments.csv'
    commentList = readFile(fileName)
    # add an entry to the skills list
    name = request.form[('name')]   
    date = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X", gmtime())
    #adds the current date and time
    comment = request.form[('comment')]
    newComment=[name,date,comment]
    commentList.append(newComment)
    #save the skills list to the file
    writeFile(commentList, fileName)
    return redirect('comments')
```

```html
<ul class="comments">
 {% for comments in commentList %}<br>
 <b><li>{% for names in comments %}</li>  <!-- I think the problem is here-->
 <li>{{names}}</li></b>
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: `<b>` should be inside the `<li>` tags

Comment: What problem are you actually getting?

Comment: I suppose that my list is not perfect.
Also, the problem could be in the .py file : 
aList = [row for row in reader]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The list should look like this :

```html
 <ul class="comments">
    
        {% for line in commentList %}
            <li> <b>{{ line[0] }}</b> <br> <b>{{ line[1] }}</b> <br> {{ line[2] }} </li><br>
        {% endfor %}

 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTML <li> list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp) from W3Schools, [lists in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html) from W3C.

```
 <ol>
 <li>Coffee</li>
 <li>Tea</li>
 <li>Milk</li>
 </ol>

 <ul>
 <li>Coffee</li>
 <li>Tea</li>
 <li>Milk</li>
 </ul>
```

For breaks in `<li>`...`</li>` rows br-tags are good and can be used. `<li>` ... `<br>` ... `<br>` ... `</li>`. br-tags are single. [HTML <br> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) from W3Schools.

```
<li> ... <br> ... <br> ... </li>
```

Always remember the rule: in HTML content better stick to [a-z][0-9]. So no curly braces and no percentage symbol in testing.